# Copy SQL Azure Database to different Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

SQL Azure database supports copying whole database asynchronously with a single command as below:

I have  been using to copy database within same server using

```
CREATE DATABASE [targetdb] AS COPY OF [sourcedb]
```

But when I try to copy database to a different SQL Azure server:

```
CREATE DATABASE [targetdb] AS COPY OF [source_sql_azure_server].[sourcedb]
```

But I get below error:

Cannot open server "source_sql_azure_server" requested by the login. The login failed.

How do I copy?

Answer (score 19):

Although this question is very old, it's the one I came across when trying to find out if I could easily copy an Azure SQL database from one server to another.

It turns out that it's now as simple as navigating to the source database from http://portal.azure.com then clicking copy and choosing the new destination server.

The whole process is explained in more detail in this article:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-copy/

Comment: How fast is it for 1GB Db in the same region?

Comment: @Artyom Runs for about 5 min now

Answer (score 4):

To execute DB copy between 2 different servers you must be connected to the master database of the destination SQL Azure server and have correct permissions.
*The exact same login/password* must exist on the source server and destination server and the login must have `db_owner` permissions on the source server and `dbmanager` on the destination server.

Read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951624.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is also another way to achieve another copy in a different region. You can simply do an Asynchronous Replication to a different server and region and make that the primary.

Comment: For the sake of completeness in this answer, how would accomplish this.  Examples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your 5 year old problem! :)

```
   $dblist = @("db1","db2","db3")
   $sourceserver = "azureDBserversource"
   $targetserver = "azureDBserverTarget"
   $sourceRG = "mySourceRG"
   $targetRG = "myTargetRG"

    foreach ($db in $dblist) {
            New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName $sourceRG `
                -ServerName $sourceserver `
                -DatabaseName $db `
                -CopyResourceGroupName  $targetRG `
                -CopyServerName $targetserver `
                -CopyDatabaseName $db
            }
```